# Bootstrap navbar responsive with big logo

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive, bootstrap-4

i'm trying to create a navbar with logo, like this layout: [Layout on desktop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zKN62.png)

and with mobile, like this layout: [Layout on mobile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ynlAC.png)

In the first layout, i need that the navbar is center vertically. I have write this snippets of code:

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <a href="#" class="pull-left">
                <img src="image/logo.png" height="300px" id="logo" class="img-responsive">
            </a>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-9">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle"
                            data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#example-navbar-collapse">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="example-navbar-collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li><a href="#">Search</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Archives</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Education</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>
```

That's work, except the vertically centered navbar and the logo on mobile go under the navbar, how i can obtain this two layout? Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try `align="center"`:

```
<div align="center" style="max-height:inherit">
 <div class="col-md-9">
        <nav align="center" class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle"
                        data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#example-navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="example-navbar-collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a href="#">Search</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Archives</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Education</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>
```

And please tell me if it works.

Comment: Well .. change it to Div    <div align="center" class="col-md-9">

Comment: Well i am use this code and its works good for me .. i just wanna Help you . now try to but new div .. this Code  <div align="center" style="max-height:inherit"> </div>

Comment: i am Update my Answer

Comment: Thanks but for me not work, i need to center vertically the navbar, no the item of navbar

Answer (score 0):

Your images do not appear making the question unclear on what you're trying to achieve. From what I understand is that you run out of space on mobile causing the elements to stack. Try adding a resizing attribute to the logo to make it a compatible size for mobile. Please revise your question though.

Comment: No the problem is not the stack, the stack is ok, but the logo is hidden from navbar, the two layout rappresent that I want.

Comment: The two layouts aren't being displayed on my browser, can you please re-upload them

Comment: Oh sorry, Try now